# Open a .blend file and start rendering

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine

I am looking for a way to start rendering a .blend file the moment it is opened.
Doing this with a python script that is executed on load is not an option.

That setup will render the image before the interface is fully shown.
So basically you're looking at a grey screen until the image is fully rendered in the background.

What I want is that when the file is openend, it starts rendering and you can see the rendering process.
Ideally, Blender should quit when the render is completed.

Comment: If you aren't going to interact with the interface, why not use the [command line](https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=render+from+command+line)?

Comment: @NᴏᴠɪᴄᴇIɴDɪsɢᴜɪsᴇ Not a dup, but it is related.

Comment: @iKlsR Well, I want to visually show the rendering process. I've built a file for that is driven by a bunch of parameters in an XML file. That way my client can update that XML file using a simple UI and launch the render. I could just tell them to press F12 but if the file starts rendering immediately, what would be even better.

Comment: @NᴏᴠɪᴄᴇIɴDɪsɢᴜɪsᴇ This is hardly a duplicate.

Comment: Don't see how this is a duplicate.